# How to put image URL in src using Avatar materialui

Tags: javascript, material-ui

my image's source is ->

> src/assets/images/doctor1.jpg

and i want to use that image here ->

> src/components/docNotes/docNotes.js

inside docNotes.js file i tried ->

```
<Avatar className={classes.avtar} alt="Remy Sharp" src={'../../assets/images/doctor1.jpg'} />
```

I have been playing with this few hours but not able to get image in Avatar. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I also tried to use the way suggested by [Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/components/avatars/) but it doent's work (I don't know why).

I solved using `import` in this way:

```
import mia from "./src/assets/images/mia.png";

export default function MyAvatar(props) {
  return <Avatar src={mia} />;
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-of-avatar-forked-xeh17?file=/demo.js) a codesandbox example.